# Unable to access response object NOT AUTHORIZED related info after Blob conversion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In my react app, I am using the following approach to download a file using axios.

**Approach 1:**

```
axios.post('api/downloadMyFile', data, { responseType: 'blob' })
.then(blob=>{
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob.data); 
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = "download.zip"  
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
})
```

Initially I was using this "Approach 2" but then had to change to "Approach 1" for the following reason:

The `response.data` returned from Axios is a JSON string. So creating a Blob from that JSON doesn't produce the correct object. More info on this is in my [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897447/handling-file-download-from-api-call/64899328?noredirect=1#comment114743898_64899328).

**Approach 2:**

```
axios.post('api/downloadMyFile',
    data
  ).then((response) => {

      console.log("Response testing ");
      console.log(response.data);

    }
```

The problem I am facing after switching to "Approach 1" is as follows:

In some case, webservice call can return `NOT AUTHORIZED` in the `response.data`. But since in "Approach 1" I am  telling Axios to provide the response in the form of a Blob, all I see in `console.log(blob)` is the following:

[image]

Had I been using "Approach 2", and there was a scenario of `NOT_AUTHORIZED`, I would have seen something like this in `console.log(response)`:

```
Object { data: "NOT_AUTHORIZED: you are not allowed to download this file", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
```

Considering I am using approach 1, how can I access `NOT_AUTHORIZED` related information?

Answer (score 0):

backend should return a specific status code like 422 to mark that this response is not `ok`, and the extra info about the error is going to be sent in JSON.

on frontend side, you can try parse the `response.data.text()` to JSON, then read the errorCode or errorMessage to detect the detail reason why this file cannot be download.

Below is sample code that worked for me:

```
axios.post(`/tickets/download`, someFilterParams, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  responseType: 'blob',
}).then(async (res) => {
  if (res.status !== 200) {
    const errorAsJSON = JSON.parse(await res.data.text());
    console.log('error: ', errorAsJSON);
  } else {
    // save file
  }
});
```