# trying to download file directly from response of an api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, .net

I have an api response which return a xlsx file as response.

the api is triggered on button click and I need to download it as on response.

every api call is gone through a service which handles appends token to the url for authentication purposes.which basically means that I cannot use methods like this [the one mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897447/handling-file-download-from-api-call). the response I am getting is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxQL0.png) ( [response when debugged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgZ9e.png) ). I have tried

`a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response)`

and

`a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new blob([response]))`

and tried downloading but but spreadsheet is corrupted ( I know the file is fine sice swagger returns the file properly).

how do I get this file as that of in swagger [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khX9a.png) so that i can download in `a.click()`.

this is my [api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUQcE.png)  from dot net

thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? 

```const myLink = document.createElement('a');
    myLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobFile);
    myLink.download = fileName;
    myLink.click();```

Comment: @Klian response is not a blob file I think. That is another issue I am facing as well. not sure about the file type I am getting. when debugged it looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgZ9e.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the axios instance.

I have added response type to the request header, the issue was solved.

```
        responseType: "blob",
```

this was the root cause. After that I was able to download the file with response provided by 'Klian' in the comments to my question.

Comment: Same here, setting ```responseType: "blob"```  in the axios request worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `FileSaver.js` library to download the file.
Here is the sample code:

```
import FileSaver from 'file-saver';

// Call your API to get the response
axios.get('/PrintWorkSheet', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then((response) => 
    {
        //Create a Blob object from the response data
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

        // Use FileSaver.js to save the Blob as a file
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'WorkSheet.xlsx');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```